# WPF Printing issue

Tags: wpf, printing

I have to do printing of visuals say Grid contents, over multiple pages supporting basic printing functionalities like changing the margin, orientation ,paper size etc without invoking Print Dialog.
 1. So should I use Custom Printing or Will Print document serve my purpose? 
 2. If Print document allows these features, please let me know how to convert the visual as a IDocumentPaginatorSource to pass it to the Print Document function?

Please reply asap...Very urgent...

Answer (score 0):

for printing visual u can use printdialog.printvsual it will solve your problem.
[Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/printing-in-wpf) sample to print visual.